# While viewing a man page, how can I see the directory it was loaded from? (e.g., for local share vs system share determination)?

Tags: linux, manpage

I am just trying to figure out from which absolute path the currently viewed man page was loaded - its absolute path filename.

Answer (score 5):

The command `man --path` will give you all of the directories that `man` will search for a given manpage, and it takes an optional argument, where it searches for that man page and returns the path to it.

For instance, if you want to view the location of the `man` entry for `ls`, you'd run the following:

```
$ man --path ls
/usr/share/man/man1/ls.1
```

If your system is set up to use a pager like `less` for displaying man pages, you can type `!man --path ls` from inside the man page to find the location of the file as well.